# How to create Popover in ipad?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I want to develop a popover in my iPad application. A UIButton trigger will call the popover and that popover will contain a UITableViewController.

First I need a popover.

Need some example code or direction or link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the sample code in the [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ToolbarSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009461).  You should also look at the [UIPopoverController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverController).

Comment: Thanx for sharing the documentation.

Answer (score 14):

in your viewcontroller on the button action write this code:

```
- (IBAction)openAllRhymes:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    PopupTableView *tableViewController = [[PopupTableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];


    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tableViewController];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(button.frame.size.width / 2, button.frame.size.height / 1, 1, 1) inView:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    [tableViewController release];
}
```

Now you have created a tableview for popover in that tableviewcontroller write:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(108,400);
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html), it's all in there. If you don't understand it, start with general [tutorials](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514) on iOS development or ask specifically about the parts you don't understand. You will need a solid understanding of how view controllers work before it makes sense to work with popovers. The [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW4) also has a section specifically about popovers.

Answer (score 2):

```
  TAableViewController *tableViewController = [[[TAableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TAableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                   initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];


    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
    [nav release];
    popover.delegate = self;
    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 497);
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Here in this :-

1) TAbleViewController has the table you want to load .
2) i am adding this to the navigation controller
3) navigation controller to the popover